# How to block any click on the screen until dialog show animation complete?

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, countdowntimer

I'm writing puzzle game. When CountDownTimer finishes, dialog is displayed. Dialog displayed with animation. If I click anywhere on the screen until dialog showing animation is completed, then game returns to the first level. Today I noticed another unexpected behavior. I finished level at the same time with timer finish and as result I had two dialogs: TimeOverDialog and LevelCompleteDialog. So, what I have to do to solve this problem? 
Sorry for my English!

Answer (score 0):

Add **dialog.setCancelable(false);** in alertDialog code.